Keep getting error# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137 throw err; ^, whe running index.js file
I am running command node index.js and getting below error:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137 throw err; ^

Error: Cannot find module '../models/User' Require stack:

/home/ubuntu/travel-community/server/routes/auth.js /home/ubuntu/travel-community/server/index.js at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19) at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18) at Object. (/home/ubuntu/travel-community/server/routes/auth.js:4:14) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19) { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ '/home/ubuntu/travel-community/server/routes/auth.js', '/home/ubuntu/travel-community/server/index.js' ] } Node.js v18.19.1

I have checked and files are in right place. Below is the configuration:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-235:~/travel-community/server$ ls

config index.js models node_modules package-lock.json package.json routes
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-235:~/travel-community/server$ cd routes/
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-235:~/travel-community/server/routes$ ls

auth.js
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-235:~/travel-community/server/routes$ cd ..
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-235:~/travel-community/server$ ls

config index.js models node_modules package-lock.json package.json routes
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-235:~/travel-community/server$ cat index.js

const express = require('express'); 
const connectDB = require('./config/db'); 
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

const app = express(); connectDB();

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(Server running on port ${PORT}));

Can someone please help.
I am using AWS Ubuntu 24 (free tier).

Please fix the formatting of the error message. But in any case, it's clearly telling you that one of the modules you're trying to require() doesn't exist.
